# Can i Un-publish QnA Maker knowledge base?

Tags: c#, azure-qna-maker

This article: [QnA Maker limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/limits) explains that you can have only two published knowledge bases in Free tier.

If I have 3 KBs, is there way to un-publish one of them so I can publish other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting issue on AzureDocs got this reply, and it somehow works.

> You can export the knowledge base which is not required using the
> export knowledge base option from the settings tab of your KB. This is
> available for export in .csv or .tsv formats. This should allow you to
> publish your new KB in the free tier and you can create a new KB with
> the exported KB without publishing it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't. You'd have to delete your knowledgebase. That being said, you can ask [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new?title=&body=%0A%0A%5BEnter%20feedback%20here%5D%0A%0A%0A---%0A%23%23%23%23%20Document%20Details%0A%0A%E2%9A%A0%20*Do%20not%20edit%20this%20section.%20It%20is%20required%20for%20learn.microsoft.com%20%E2%9E%9F%20GitHub%20issue%20linking.*%0A%0A*%20ID%3A%201875f6a8-0237-2dbb-6b9b-624ee0b675bf%0A*%20Version%20Independent%20ID%3A%2001992c42-d7bf-d4d0-4ba1-3e1358c4b885%0A*%20Content%3A%20%5BTroubleshooting%20-%20QnA%20Maker%20-%20Azure%20Cognitive%20Services%5D(https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fcognitive-services%2FQnAMaker%2Ftroubleshooting%3Ftabs%3Dv1)%0A*%20Content%20Source%3A%20%5Barticles%2Fcognitive-services%2FQnAMaker%2Ftroubleshooting.md%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoftDocs%2Fazure-docs%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Farticles%2Fcognitive-services%2FQnAMaker%2Ftroubleshooting.md)%0A*%20Service%3A%20**cognitive-services**%0A*%20Sub-service%3A%20**qna-maker**%0A*%20GitHub%20Login%3A%20%40nerajput1607%0A*%20Microsoft%20Alias%3A%20**nerajput**)

That's the link to open an issue on the 'Troubleshooting for QnA Maker' official documentation, as that is an excellent question and it should have been answered there.